# Magento Order submit Invoice fails and gives strangest error

Tags: admin, sales-order, invoice, ce-1.9.2.1

My client's site is running on Magento ce-1.9.2.1.

Now he says for a particular order, whenever he tries to Generate invoice and then submit the same, he gets below error, which even I found for the first time:

```
We were not able to recognize the list of articles in this order. Please make sure that the article numbers match the order and try again.
```

Please advise and suggest something about this.

Answer (score 1):

This message is not part of Magento itself, it is probably coming from a payment extension.

Search for the message in `app/code` to see where it is triggered and/or ask your payment provider, they probably know what it means.